# Resharper - How to disable find usages OR use the old find usages

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper

I can't stand the resharper find usage.
How do I go back to the default one? (F12 / Shift F12)?
(Visual Studio 2010)

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way currently to revert back to the Visual Studio 'Find References'

What you can do however is:
1) Change 'Group by:' to None

[image]

2) Change 'Group by:' to File

[image]

While this does not 'answer' the question I do urge you to *try* Resharpers Find Usages. I must admit I also had an issue with Resharpers 'Find Usages' window and wanted to revert to Visual Studios one but after discovering no way to go back without uninstalling/disabling Reshaper I find their window much more powerful and I now find VS's one inferior.

Comment: fair enough, not sure what machine you're on, its quick on mine. the first time you search for something Resharper will build a cache and subsequent searches should be much faster

Comment: I don't like how the Resharper window docks instead of showing as a popup. I want all the available space to see the results and I don't need to see anything else at the same time so a docked window makes no sense.

Comment: I am also searching for same solution because this one is super-slow.

Comment: 'None' does not show the file, which is important information, when looking for a specific usage.

Comment: @AMissico Group by 'Project Structure' then. you can use the icons to expand/collapse the usages; initially it is different to what you're used to but it is better in my opinion as the usages are grouped by your project so you can quickly ignore ones that arent relevant (eg usages in your unit tests)

Comment: So, there is no way to disable this window? It's super annoying

Comment: @JuanZamudio how exactly is it 'super annoying' ? (thanks for the down vote too!)

Comment: @wal: Well, the down vote is because a workaround it's not an answer (at least for me, in stackoverflow it appears that most of the time there are workarounds than direct answers) and its annoying because adds so much noise, the default window is very lean, different strokes I guess

Comment: @AMissico you can 'Group by' File.

Comment: @wal, it is not the same. I just do not want to use "Find Usage" feature of ReSharper.